# Using 3G modem to make a voice call

Tags: delphi, usb, voice, 3g, modem

Most of the 3G modems (USB sticks) support voice calls, but all of them can do this only through the dashboard software which is shipped with them.

Do you have any information, how to get the voice from and pass the mic data to the 3G modem in Delphi?

When I plug in, it installs 4 COM ports:

- NEMA
- Diagnostic
- Application Interface
- standard COM port which can be used to pass AT commands

Currently, via the standard COM port I can pass the *ATDT12345678* command to call a number, the connection establishes, and the other end is ringing. When I answer the call, I don't hear anything - neither on the computer which the 3G modem is connected to, nor on the called phone.

Any answer or workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Googling "3g modems usb api" turns up some links that might help you.

Comment: you dont hear anything because you have to answer with carrier etc

Comment: I've googled for that phrase, but there wasn't any relevant result. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: There's no carrier in 3G modems. These are digital devices. I you hear a carrier it is because the dialer application plays a tone for you...

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://www.saveondish.com/forum/T-Activate-the-Voice-Calling-on-Huawei-HSPA-modems. If you look around the net, the answer is no, except for huawei modems...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: The modem I'm using already has activated voice functionality. As I wrote, in it's dashboard I can dial a number and I can hear the voice of the other end. I want to do the same from my own software.

Comment: Yeah but you must *FORCE* you modem into voice mode before you do ATDT or else the modem will want to do a DATA call, not a VOICE call. Since you did not post a specific model, I can not give you the exact commands...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I have 4 modems: ZTE K3772-Z, Huawei E173, ZTE MF110, and a 4th one which is a brandless bulk modem from China. If you know any of these, or the command to switch to Voice mode, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I've checked your solution. The modem is now unlocked, and according to dc-unlocker the voice is activated. When I send the AT^CVOICE=? command it says: ^CVOICE:(1), so it's active. I've send the AT^U2DIAG=5 command, it says OK. I've dialed with ATDT12345(some number) and the situation is the same, I can't hear the mic of my laptop, and when I talk to the phone I've called, my voice can not be heared on the laptop's speakers. Any idea?

Comment: @JanDoggen: Did you get it resolved? I have similar query. Besides, I have http://www.flipkart.com/micromax-mmx144f-ferrari-opus-data-card/p/itmdbf2uwn4ntfc3

Comment: @anubhav16 Wasn't me ;-)

Comment: @anubhav16 No, I couldn't. I've tried also using the chan_dongle module for Asterisk to get it work, but it was also without success. I'm giving up...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place a voice call, you must put the modem in voice mode.

These are the AT commands for a Huawei E173:

```
Activation: AT^U2DIAG=5 

Reset: AT^U2DIAG=276 

Status: AT^CVOICE=?
```

If it does not work, you need to unlock the voice dialing feature with [dc unlocker](https://www.dc-unlocker.com/downloads/get/03FpJrhM).

Comment: In the good old days I believe Windows TAPI had some features to make this easy. not sure if TAPI still applies in this case though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the link you've attached is for Voice Modems (those which connect to landline) and not for 3G Modems. 3G modems are a bit different, and they are not hundred percently compatible with the Hayes AT commands.

Comment: TAPI is also not a good solution, it also available for simple analogue Voice modems, and not for 3Gs.